# SQL TIME change format in Database?

Tags: mysql, sql, time, format

In my Database I have a column "length" from type TIME where the values are like 02:20:00 but I want them all to be 00:02:20

Is there any way to do?
I have over 5000 rows so I can't change it with UPDATE.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? SQL Server?

Comment: I'm not very experienced in this stuff, I'm simply using phpmyadmin, SQL as far as I know.

Comment: @user3566608: Then you are most probably using MySQL. Every DB engine uses a slightly different syntax and has different functions available.

Comment: What does the column represent?  What is it's datatype?

Comment: Thank you guys but juergen d's answer solved my problem. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update your_table
set length = time(concat('00:', hour(length), ':', minute(length)))
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/36248)